Visual Studio Spell Checker Remove language
Currently, I have to go through 3 menus to get to the en-GB spelling
Is there a way to remove en-US (which I don't use) from the spell checker? which I am hoping will reduce this to only 2 menus?

I only have GB English in the Language settings of Windows.
I only have English in the VS installation settings (Modify)



You can customize spell checker with switch
spelling_languages = en-GB

.editorconfig file.
Make sure to install the language pack in your system.

Isn't this for the solution though? is there a way to do it at the VS application level so it applies to all solutions I open?

Turns out you can add an .editorconfig to the folder containing all your projects, which kind of helps to make it application wide. And you don't need the underscore before/after
